# what's the best practice for not calling watchers in response to the initial load of JSON data

Tags: vue.js

I make a simple axios get call to load external data and assign to data elements. We are setting one of our forms v-models at this step. Also, our v-model is going to show a modal when changed via a watcher. Is there a way in Vuejs to tell the watcher to ignore that initial first transition from null to post-axios load? Right now, the modal gets displayed after the JSON load.

```
<select v-model="selectedSiteReport">
  <option v-for="siteReport in siteReports" :value="siteReport.id">
    {{siteReport.report_name}}
  </option>
</select>
....
data: {
  selectedSiteReport: null, 
  siteReports: null
},
watch: {
  selectedSiteReport: function(){
    alert("selectedSiteReport was changed");
},
mounted: function(){
  var that = this;
  axios.get('/api/v1/site_reports/<%=@site_report.id %>')
    .then(function (response) {
      that.siteReports = response.data.site_reports;
      that.selectedSiteReport = _.filter(that.siteReports, ['is_current', true])[0].id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

```js
watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    question: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
        this.answer = 'Waiting for you to stop typing...'
        this.debouncedGetAnswer()
    }
},
```

** Edit ** i was right first. check if the oldValue is null, do nothing... or if the oldValue is not null, do something...

just add an if to check if the old value is not equal to the declared data value which in your case is null

You should end up with something like:

```js
watch: {
    selectedSiteReport: function(newV, oldV){
        if(oldV != null){
            alert("selectedSiteReport was changed");
        }
    },
}
```